# Technique on proving equality

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Do we have a technique in proving equality that says if $A$ is contained in $B$ and the cardinality of $A$ is equal to the cardinality of $B$ then $A=B$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The set of integers and the set of even integers make a counterexample. Because both have the same cardinality

Answer (score 4):

Here's a proof for finite sets (as mentioned, the claim is false for infinite sets; take $A=\mathbb{N}$ and $B=\mathbb{Q}$).

Suppose $A\subset B$, but $A\neq B$.  Write $B=A\cup (B-A)$.  Since $\#B$ is finite and $A\cap(B-A)=\emptyset$, we have $\#B=\#A+\#(B-A)$.  Now, since $A\neq B$, $B-A$ is nonempty, so $\#(B-A)>0$ and hence $\#B>\#A$.

Comment: Your proof could be simplified somewhat by removing the contradiction. Just write $B = A \cup (B - A)$ and deduce $\#(B-A) = 0$ using exactly the same steps as you have here.

Comment: Absolutely.  Sometimes I find contrapositive/contradiction proofs more intuitive to start out with though ("what happens if its not true?"), then convert to a direct argument if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If $A$ is Dedekind-finite (which means finite in the context of most modern set theory), and $B\subseteq A$ then $A=B$ if and only if $|A|=|B|$.

In fact this is an equivalent definition for Dedekind-finite sets. Namely, $A$ is Dedekind-finite if and only if it is true that if $B\subseteq A$ and $|A|=|B|$ then $A=B$.

The natural numbers are *not* Dedekind-finite. For example, $\mathbb N\setminus\{0\}\neq\mathbb N$, but both have the same cardinality.